# Execute some code before Controller in every request on Symfony3

Tags: symfony, event-listener

I need to execute some code before Symfony 3 controllers are executed.

I read this guide: http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html that explains how to do it.

But in this point:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher/before_after_filters.html#tag-controllers-to-be-checked the documentation explains that we need to specify what controllers will be affected by this `EventListener` using `implements TokenAuthenticatedController` on each Controller we need, but since I want to execute code before *every* controller (all), I hope that exists some way to do it without add the `implements` on all my Controllers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you really need to execute the code on every request? Then maybe you should rather look at the available KernelEvents (especially kernel.request and kernel.controller). Go to: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel.html for more details like main and sub-requests.

Also your controllers don't actually need to implement anything. 
The `TokenAuthenticatedController` is only implemented in the example to execute:

```
if ($controller[0] instanceof TokenAuthenticatedController) {
        $token = $event->getRequest()->query->get('token');
        if (!in_array($token, $this->tokens)) {
            throw new AccessDeniedHttpException('This action needs a valid token!');
        }
    }
```

If you don't intend to do anything with the controller in your listener and do some other stuff you can just do whatever you like, given everything you need to do your work is injected into the listener and available at that point.

Edit from the docs:

> A kernel.controller listener gets notified on every request, right before the controller is executed. So, first, you need some way to identify if the controller that matches the request needs token validation.

If you want to execute your code regardless of which controller is finally executed you don't need the before mentioned way to identify which controller will be executed therefore is no need for the interface at all.

Comment: I don't know why but when I only read this line `if ($controller[0] instanceof TokenAuthenticatedController) {` I know that something smells bad.

Comment: Well it's from the official docs the op linked and it's incomplete. The doc explicitly states you either get a `Closure` or a `Class` when calling `getController` and if it's a Class you'll get it wrapped in an array. Not optimal but given the information absolutely fine.

Comment: I know it's from the official documentation but I meant that having such a subscriber handling any controllers instead of just one controller (defined through configuration mapping) sucks in Symfony.

I've been working with Laravel since years and it's cleaner than Symfony to do specific stuff based on specific controller than Symfony.

Answer (score 2):

In the example showed in the docs, the `interface TokenAuthenticatedController` is used only to execute specific code on all controllers that implements that interface to prevent to be execuded on every request in all controllers.

keep in mind that maybe you need to check if you really want to execute the code in every request type or only in predefined type like **master** requests as described in [Events and Event Listeners](http://symfony.com/doc/current/event_dispatcher.html#request-events-checking-types).